# Select top 10 percent, also bottom percent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, percentile

I have two questions:

1. When using the `select top 10 percent` statement, for example on a test database with 100 scores, like this:

   ```
   Select top 10 percent score 
   from test
   ```

   Would SQL Server return the 10 highest scores, or just the top 10 obs based on how the data look like now (e.g. if the data is entered into database in a way that lowest score appears first, then would this return the lowest 10 scores)?
2. I want to be able to get the top 10 highest scores and bottom 10 lowest scores out of this 100 scores, what should I do?

Comment: USE Order By your score field and apply SELECT TOP 10 or BOTTOM 10 as per your need

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, number 1 is meaningless. Nothing is guaranteed because tables have *no* inherent order.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `NTILE` window function to group your scores into 10 groups of data - group no. 1 would be the lowest 10%, group no. 10 would be the top 10%:

```
;WITH Percentile AS
(
    SELECT
        Score,
        ScoreGroup = NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY Score)
    FROM
        test
)
SELECT * 
FROM Percentile
WHERE ScoreGroup IN (1, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `UNION ALL` means that it will count all rows twice.

You can do it with a single count as below. Whether or not this will be more efficient will depend (e.g. on indexes).

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                1E0 * ROW_NUMBER()
                        OVER (
                          ORDER BY score) / COUNT(*)
                                                  OVER() AS p
         FROM   test)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  p < 0.1
        OR p > 0.9
```

Comment: I've seen "1E0" before in code and I'm curious as to what behavior you're looking for with it.  Is it short-hand for an implicit numeric cast or conversion?  I know it means 1*10^0.

Comment: @cdc it just casts to float to avoid integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
select score from 
    (Select top 10 percent score
     from test
     order by score desc
    )a
union all   
select score from 
   (select top 10 percent score
    from test
    order by score asc
   )b
```

if duplicates are allowed use **union**

Comment: I think use of UNION and UNION ALL has been reversed in above query

Answer (score 0):

Use ascending in your query for the top 90. Then, descending in your query for the top 10. Then, union these two queries